# SQL - Suppressing duplicate columns (not rows) for a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns something like this...

*Dataset 1:*

```
EFFECTIVE_DATE END_DATE DESC                            SUBPART

4/10/2011                  Dairy Products Processing           L
4/10/2011                  360 CMR 10.000   
4/1/2011       4/9/2011    Dairy Products Processing            A
4/1/2011       4/9/2011    Ferroalloy Manufacturing             A
```

I'm looking to get a query that returns that dataset like this...

*Dataset 2:*

```
   EFFECTIVE_DATE END_DATE  DESC                            SUBPART

    4/10/2011                 Dairy Products Processing           L
                             360 CMR 10.000 
    4/1/2011        4/9/2011   Dairy Products Processing           A
                               Ferroalloy Manufacturing         A
```

Notice that the duplicate effective date( 4/10/2011 - {null} and 4/1/2011 - 4/9/2011) are suppressed when duplicated.

**Edit 1:**  In response to @Justin Cave's answer,

Below is my query merged with Justin Cave's template.  It's close, but its a little off.  The dates and descriptions seem a little mixed up from what they're supposed to be (the data in the dataset should be like the one in *Dataset 2:*.  I think it may have something to do with my ordering but I'm not sure.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN effective_date = prior_effective_date 
             THEN null
             ELSE effective_date
         END) effective_date,
       (CASE WHEN end_date = prior_end_date 
             THEN null
             ELSE end_date
         END) end_date,
       cfr_part_desc ,
       cfr_subpart
  FROM
    (SELECT c.effective_date,
            lag(c.effective_date) over (order by c.effective_date desc, cpl.cfr_part_desc asc) prior_effective_date,
            c.end_date,
            lag(c.end_date) over  (order by c.effective_date desc, cpl.cfr_part_desc asc) prior_end_date,
            cpl.CFR_PART_DESC as cfr_part_desc,
            cd.CFR_SUBPART as cfr_subpart
     from table1 c
      inner join table2 cd ON c.IND_ID = cd.IND_ID
                              AND cd.EFFECTIVE_DATE = c.EFFECTIVE_DATE
      inner join table3 cpl on cd.CFR_PART_L_S = cpl.CFR_PART_L_S 
      inner join table4 f on c.ind_id = f.ind_id
      inner join table5 p on f.ind_id = p.ind_id
    where p.PERMIT_S = '4988'
    order by c.effective_date desc, cpl.CFR_PART_DESC asc
    );
```

[image]

**Edit 2:**  The incorrect data was due to ambiguously defining the column effective date.  The query above now works correctly.

Comment: Why do you need that at all? IMHO it's up to your client to display the data according to your needs. Don't do it with SQL.

Comment: unfortunately the way the system is setup this must be done.  (Its a legacy system).  Pretty much, I construct my sql statement, use aspose and XML and display the output of the query in a MS word document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this using analytic functions.  It's not clear to me how the result set is ordered, so you'll have to fill that in.  You'll also probably be able to combine the analytic function into your query rather than adding a third level of nesting.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN effective_date = prior_effective_date 
             THEN null
             ELSE effective_date
         END) effective_date,
       (CASE WHEN end_date = prior_end_date 
             THEN null
             ELSE end_date
         END) end_date,
       description ,
       subpart
  FROM
    (SELECT effective_date,
            lag(effective_date) over 
                (order by effective_date desc, description asc) prior_effective_date,
            end_date,
            lag(end_date) over 
                (order by effective_date desc, description asc) prior_end_date,
            desc,
            subpart
       FROM <<your query>>)
```

Comment: I have it so close to working.  I'm sorting by effective_date descending.  Could you update your answer with my sort?  Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @contactmatt - How do you know that "Dairy Products Processing" comes before "360 CMR 10.000" if both `effective_date` values are the same?  Or is there a difference with the time component?

Comment: Nothing was specified by the client we're working with, but I think it'd make sense to sort by the description ascending.  (There's no time component)

Comment: @contactmatt - OK.  Updated the ORDER BY in the analytic functions

Comment: @Justin Cave, thank you!  I updated my question to include my query merged with your template and a screenshot of the returned dataset.  It's just a little off and I don't know what it is.  I think it may be something with the sorting.

Comment: The error I was receiving was my fault.  I fixed my portion of the query and it now works.  Thanks for all your help!  Seriously, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL*Plus to generate the output, you can use `BREAK`:

```
BREAK ON EFFECTIVE_DATE ON END_DATE
SELECT ...
```